# gdb internals and setuid bit

Tags: linux, gdb

I understand the fact that, in the case of setuid program, ptrace doesn't work well without root privilege. Then, how does gdb work with setuid bit enabled executable and non-root privilege?

To explore, I tested it with a simple exec("/bin/id","id",NULL) executable.

In the case of running the executable on gdb with non-root privilege, the execution was successful but the euid didn't change to that of root(=0). So, I suspected that when setuid bit is set, inside gdb, the executable binary is being copied as a temporary file before the execution. This seems to be correct since when the "read" permission of the executable is removed, gdb prints out "Permission denied" when non-root user uses gdb for the executable.

Could anyone, who knows gdb well, confirm or correct this idea?

Thanks for your help!

p.s. Besides, I used gdb (Debian 8.3.1-1) 8.3.1

Comment: 1. gdb is using ptrace(2). 2. the kernel will IGNORE the setuid bit of an executable when the process calling execve(2) is running under ptrace. there's nothing special about gdb.

Comment: gdb wants to open the executable (and fails if it's not readable) in order to read debugging symbols, shared libraries info, etc not to copy it elsewhere ;-)

Comment: Oh thanks, I once thought read permission is not required for normal operation after I tested with root. Then, I realized that root bypass all the privilege check lol